Make.com multiple node path "unification"
Heading into the dark underworld of "low-code" to see what it's all about, I am bumping my head against what is a super simple task to accomplish using normal coding.
I am trying to read Google Adwords metrics, get data for clicks, impressions, cost and campaign name, and then output that to whatever my next flow-node is going to be.
I am having an extremely challenging time understanding how to achieve this with make. Right now, I have separate node paths to "extract" specific metrics from the incoming array bundle. One for each metric.
I do not understand how to get all of this back into "one" flow, to use them all together.
Data Store
I ended up outputting each value to a data store, which should have solved my problem, but the nodes don't fire in sequential order, and my "final" node, which is supposed to read the data store, fires before the previous nodes added their values.
Delay
I tried adding a delay to my final node, where I want to read all values from the data store, but this delays the entire execution, not just the node path.
I am pretty sure I am missing "something" inherently specific to the type of platforms vs. normal coding flow.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?


To whomever runs into this.
Here is what I figured out.
For each "abandoned" route, if you will, you need to set a variable with a unique variable name.
You then have to determine, based on the "flow" that Make.com decides on, which is the last route that fires. In this last route, you can then use the 'get multiple variables' module to collect the previous variables set in the individual routes.
The variables aren't detected as part of the normal interface though, so it looks like you can't choose them. Just type in the variable name in the multiple variable node, and it will collect the data assigned to this variable.

